# What are the renewal dates and fees for a micro-entity utility patent?

Tags: fees

If a US micro-entity Utility patent was granted in 2014, when is the next renewal date and what is the fee?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents - Stack Exchange questions are supposed to show some research or effort. This question does not show any research or effort.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to look up [post-grant fee table at USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/fees-and-payment/uspto-fee-schedule#Patent%20Post%20Allowance%20Fee) Please figure it out from this information. Note that Entity Status can change both during prosecution and **after** grant. You may or may not qualify as a micro-entity at the time the fee is due. Note, what the rest of the world calls a renewal fee, the U.S. calls a maintenance fee.

> Patent Maintenance Fees

Fee Code    37 CFR 1551/2551/3551   1.20(e) For maintaining an original or any reissue
   patent, due at 3.5 years

```
 Fee             1,600.00
```

```
Small Entity Fee   800.00
```

```
Micro Entity Fee   400.00
```

Fee Code    37 CFR 1552/2552/3552   1.20(f) For maintaining an original or any reissue
   patent, due at 7.5 years

```
 Fee             3,600.00
```

```
Small Entity Fee 1,800.00
```

```
Micro Entity Fee   900.00
```

To pay fees and get exact dates for fees for a specific patent see the [maintenance fee portal](https://fees.uspto.gov/MaintenanceFees/).

Comment: Thank you.   If the patent was granted June 24, 2014, then the 7.5 years will be January 2022?